# Get request not returning single item from collection with id param

Tags: mongodb, express, mongojs, mlab

I have this code that should return a single item from a tasks collection, stored in a database hosted on mLab.

```
router.get("/task/:id", function(req, res, next) { //callback function upon get
db.tasks.findOne({_id: mongojs.ObjectId(req.params._id)}, function(err, task) { //find tasks collection
    if(err) {
        res.send(err);
    } 
    res.json(task); //respond with single task as json 
    });
});
```

However when i enter the correct url (api/task/id), i receive a null response.
My code for returning all the items in the tasks collection works perfectly.

```
//Get all tasks
router.get("/tasks", function(req, res, next) { //callback function upon get
db.tasks.find(function(err, tasks) { //find tasks collection
    if(err) {
        res.send(err);
    } 
    res.json(tasks); //respond with tasks as json 
    });
});
```

Comment: Your param is named `id` and not `_id`. That's the field name in MongoDB. Here's where you named the param, `"/task/:id"` Correct this `mongojs.ObjectId(req.params._id)` to this `mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.id)`

Comment: Thanks, that did it!